# SwiftUI Share Instagram Post

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to share a post from Instagram with swiftui, but it didn't work, I didn't have any problems while sharing a story, but the post screen doesn't open when sharing a post.

```
// plist

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
        <string>instagram-stories</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me.

```
 Button {
                    if post.post_type !=  PostType.mp4.rawValue {
                     
                        let imagedData = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL)!
                        InstagramManager.instance.postImage(image: UIImage(data: imagedData as Data)!) { success in
                            print("insgram shared success =  \(success)")
                        }
                    } else {

                            let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: videoUrl!)
                            
                            InstagramManager.instance.postVideoToInstagramFeed(videoData: videoData!)
```

}

```
import SwiftUI
import Photos

final class InstagramManager : NSObject {
    
    public static let instance = InstagramManager()
    
    func postImage(image: UIImage, result:((Bool)->Void)? = nil) {
        guard let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app") else {
            if let result = result {
                result(false)
            }
            return
        }
        
        // let image = image.scaleImageWithAspectToWidth(640)
        
        do {
            try PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {
                let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                
                let assetID = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset?.localIdentifier ?? ""
                let shareURL = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + assetID
                
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL as URL) {
                    if let urlForRedirect = NSURL(string: shareURL) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(urlForRedirect)")!)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            if let result = result {
                result(false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func postVideoToInstagramFeed(videoData: NSData) {
        
        getLibraryPermissionIfNecessary { granted in
            
            guard granted else { return }
        }
        
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
            let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(Date().description).mp4"
            
            videoData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        },
        completionHandler: { success, error in
            
            if success {
                
                let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                
                fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate", ascending: false)]
                
                let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
                
                if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject {
                    
                    let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
                    let urlFeed = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
                    
                    guard
                        let url = URL(string: urlFeed)
                    else {
                        
                        print("Could not open url")
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                            
                            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                                
                                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                                    print("Sucess")
                                })
                            }
                            else {
                                
                                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                                print("Sucess")
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            
                            print("Instagram not found")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if let error = error {
                
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                
                print("Could not save the video")
            }
        })
    }

    func getLibraryPermissionIfNecessary(completionHandler: @escaping  (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        guard PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized else {
            completionHandler(true)
            return
        }
        
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            completionHandler(status == .authorized)
        }
    }
}

import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    // MARK: - UIImage+Resize
    
    func scaleImageWithAspectToWidth(_ toWidth:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let oldWidth:CGFloat = size.width
        let scaleFactor:CGFloat = toWidth / oldWidth
        
        let newHeight = self.size.height * scaleFactor
        let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}
```